# How to unwrap an element if it exists with CsQuery?

Tags: c#, jquery, dom, csquery

I'm using [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery) to read values of HTML elements.

In advance, I don't know if the `<a>` element contains a `<font>` element or not.

Is there a way to read the `InnerText` of an anchor regardless if it contains a `font`element or not?

**Scenario 1**: Text inside font element

```
 <div class="link">
     <a href="http://www.example.com/1">
          <font>Foo</font>
     </a>
</div>
```

**Scenario 2**: Text without font element

```
<div class="link">
     <a href="http://www.example.com/2">
         Foo
     </a>
 </div>
```

I've got the following working solution:

```
 var dom = CQ.CreateFromUrl("http://www.myurl.com");
 var a = new CQ(dom.Select("div.link a").InnerHTML);
 var font = a.Select("font");
 var myValue = a.Count() > 0 ? font[0].InnerText : a[0].InnerText;
```

But it's a bit messy and I'd rather just always remove the font element - if present - so I could go for the anchor value right away. Something like `Contents()` in combination with `UnWrap()`, but I haven't succeeded to make it work. Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dom = CQ.CreateFromUrl("http://www.myurl.com");
string result = dom[".link a"].Text();
```

Comment: Thx, didn't realize it was *that* simple :)